# Transparency with footer in CSS

Tags: css, footer

I am trying to make my footer transparent, I have managed to do it successfully though why does my content in the footer also change to the same transparency?

CSS -

```
**.footer {
background: #000000;
opacity:0.6;
filter:Alpha(opacity=60); /* IE8 and earlier */
margin-top: 2em;
float: left;
width: 800px;
height: 175px;
clear:both
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
line-height: 1.0em;}**
```

Then my content is in separate classes on top. How do I make that content sit on top and only the footer background / footer wrapper is tinted?

Comment: The content of the footer is part of the footer... You're in search for transparency, whether `rgba()` or formats of image like PNG-24 with transparency (so called PNG-32 but that's really PNG-24 with a transparency channel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a transparent background, e.g.

```
.footer {
  opacity: 1; // Leave this as 1
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); // This is in the form rgba(R,G,B,a) where a is your opacity
  // The rest of your CSS
}
```

Also, to maintain IE support, you would have to put something like this in your `<head>` tag

```
<!--[if IE]>

 <style type="text/css">
   .footer { 
     background:transparent;
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#3C000000,endColorstr=#3C000000); 
     zoom: 1;
   } 
 </style>

<![endif]-->
```

Where `#3C000000` is in the form aRGB, with opacity in hexadecimal (i.e. `3C` is 60%). See [csstricks](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) for more details.

Fred.

Comment: It's just a decimal to hexadecimal conversion. Just google "(your number) in hexadecimal", and it will come out with 0x##, where ## is what you want.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean, I have added the microsoft thingy above but how do I work out the startColorstr number? I can see the last 6 are the hex code, but how do I figure out the first two for each shade of opacity?

Comment: The first two numbers of the `startColorstr` represent the opacity in **hexadecimal** format. With a standard `opacity: ##%` the `##` is in **decimal** format. So, to convert a number from decimal to hexadecimal, a converter has to be used. Thus, to convert 90% to hexadecimal, I put into Google: "90 in hexadecimal" which gives `0x5A`. The `0x` is informing me that the following number is in hexadecimal format, and the `5A` is the number I put at the start of the `startColorstr` value. (`startColorstr=#5A...`)